# Referencia de librería no reconoce la clase

Tags: asp.net, mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core

Estoy separando mi proyecto por **N** capas. Pero tengo un problema, no me reconoce una clase `GuestResponse`.

> Error CS0246   The type or namespace name 'GuestResponse' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   LayerModelDb    C:\Users\Maf\source\repos\MyFirstApp\LayerModelDb\SettingContext\SettingDbContext.cs    13  Active

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**GuestResponse.cs**

```
namespace DataAccesLayer.Models
{
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ese es el problema no me reconoce el using LayerModelAccess.

Comment: Puedes compartir el namespace que esta definido en la clase `GuestResponse`?, debe tener el namespace `LayerModelAccess.AppEntity`;

Comment: Listo ya actualice no supe como insertar el código de forma bonita

Comment: Segun veo en el código que adjuntaste, tienes un `namespace` definido como `DataAccessLayer.Models` cuando deberia ser `LayerModelAccess.AppEntity` o me equivoco?

Comment: Nos muestras códigos diferentes. Como te dicen, en el código que pegas tienes `DataAccesLayer.Models` cuando en la captura es `LayerModelAccess.AppEntity`. Por otro lado, en la captura `GuestTesponse` no está como `public`,lo que probablemente sea el problema que tienes.

Comment: siiii era eso la clase no estaba publica si también me equivoque de solución gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu clase no puede encontrar `GuestResponse` porque no es pública. Añade simplemente `public` y ya podrás usarla:

```
namespace LayerModelAccess.AppEntity
{
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }
}
```